# Python3 Reliable way to check websites are alive

Tags: python-3.x

I am going through a list of websites and checking if they are alive. Originally I was using **urllib** but it was getting blocked at times. I switched to using a **ping** but even with ping sometimes I get "request timed out" even though the website is online when I visit it through my browser. Is there a reliable way to check if a website is alive?

Comment: What is your criteria for "a website is alive"? ``ping`` does not ensure a host actually serves a valid website, only that it is reachable with a protocol that is not HTTP/HTTPS.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the requests module

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except:
    print("Website is down")
```

Comment: What if the website redirects you to one of those "buy this domain" pages? This is not a reliable way to see if the website is down. The linked duplicate has the correct answer.